# Do you need consent when taking a screenshot during a video conference?

Tags: united-states, privacy, recording, workplace, consent

In a state that has "all party consent" laws when it comes to recording conversations, does taking a screenshot during a video conference (e.g. Zoom, Google Meet, etc.) require consent from everyone? (Do recording laws even apply here? Privacy laws?) Assume the screenshot doesn't have any written text, nor does it involve trade secrets, etc.

Comment: is there an reasonable expectation of privacy?

Comment: Often the video conferencing service announces to all that it is being recorded.

Comment: @ohwilleke: At least in my experience with Microsoft Teams, this only happens when using Teams' own recording feature. However, the OP asks about taking a screenshot which does not require use of the video conferencing program's builtin facilities. Heck, I can take a photograph of my computer screen with my analog camera.

Answer (score 2):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

<sup>I feel like we should have duplicates here, because I am repeating myself, but I guess it's not easy making actual duplicates, when it's just Germany where it's all the same and many other countries handle it differently for different questions.</sup>

I'll call it a "photo", because it doesn't really matter how you achieved getting a picture of others. Computer, screenshot, cellphone camera, CCTV, it's all the same. A picture is a picture.

One way it would be allowed to use that screenshot in *anything* would be if you act on behalf of the company and the company paid the person explicitely to be photographed. For example if the person is a model, working for the company on the call.

Another way would be if your coworkers as a group of people just happen to be there in the shot, while something of public interest happens in the focus of the picture.

But if it is simply your coworkers on a video software, with no special significance to the public, the only way legally publishing that photo is with their consent.

There are many specific laws at play here when you consider severe cases of unwanted pictures taken (person drunk, naked, on the toilet, underage etc) but for lighter cases (person just did not want to be in the picture) it is included in the general laws about personal rights. You can read all about it for example here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recht_am_eigenen_Bild_(Deutschland)

---

Since you asked for a screenshot without mentioning what it was for, if you actually never show that screenshot to anybody, it is fine. For example, you take a screenshot to remember who was there to write the minutes of the meeting after lunchbreak and then delete it when you got all the names right, without anybody else ever seeing it, that would be fine.

Comment: I should have specified I was referring to United States laws. I know German laws are more privacy-focused than the US.

Comment: The question said nothing about publishing.

Comment: @MichaelHall but Publishing or not is all that german law cares for in most cases (only for very intimate pictures *possession* is looked at as an infringement of the right)

Comment: But German publishing laws have absolutely nothing to do with taking a picture in the US.  It is irrelevant.

Comment: @MichaelHall "Publishing" is showing the screenshot to a friend or uploading it to the cloud or social media. Basically if you don't want to take Schrödingers Screenshot, in that state where no-one knows about it, because no-one opened it, then publishing is the very core of the issue. You also should know that we answer for all juristictions, especially since the question was not tagged US at the time I answered, and had nothing US specific in it.

Comment: Perhaps there is a German word for "publish" that doesn't translate directly, but the English word comes from the Latin "publicare" which means to make something available to the public. Showing a photo to a friend would be an example of *private*, not public use. For cloud storage or social media, a determination of public or private would depend on your settings.

Comment: I understand answers from other jurisdictions are welcome, but that wasn't my point.  The question asked only about taking a photo.  Certainly what you may do with it after that is part of a good and complete answer, but commercial publication seems to be the central theme of your answer and it isn't the question that was asked.

Comment: @MichaelHall "publishing" isn't commercial publication. It is *anything* you do with that photo that involves a second pair of eyes. If I look it up in a dictionary, it says "law: communicate to a third party". *Any* third party. Not just the general public.

Comment: Yes, I agree you can publish without being paid, it's just that you mentioned paying the subjects, so I used the word "commercial".  Anyway, letting that issue go, the definitions of "public" and "private" are well established and a merely involving a "second set of eyes" just doesn't meet any reasonable definition of public. In fact, a secret kept between two friends is almost the direct opposite.  (*a solo secret being the only higher level of privacy possible...*)  Since the question didn't even mention showing the screenshot to *anybody else*, I really don't see what your argument is...

Comment: I already told you, "public" just means a third party. Not "public" as in open to the general public. Obviously nobody will ever sue you, if you *really* keep it private, because nobody will ever know. So it is kinda self-evident whether you "published" something, if you end up getting sued, it wasn't as "private" as you thought. Keeping it under wraps and not getting caught doesn't make it legal though.

Comment: Compare it to libel. Obviously you *can* libel anybody you want, to your private friends in emails, and if they keep their mouth shut, nobody will ever know or sue you. Doesn't make it legal though. It's still libel, because you talked to a third party aka "published" it. It doesn't need to be publicized (I think that is the word you were looking for originally).

Comment: But that's not what public or publish means at all.  Look them up... and again, the question asked nothing about sharing with anyone. It just asked about taking a screenshot.  If we can't agree on that then no discussion will be of any use.  I will simply downvote and move on...

Comment: Then do so, I literally cannot do any more then quote a dictionary to you. If you do not believe the dictionary, I cannot help.

Comment: You actually haven't quoted a dictionary, that's the problem.  How about I start?  Oxford:   **Public** 1. of or concerning **the people as a whole**. 2. done, perceived, or existing **in open view**.

Comment: to make known *to another* or to the public generally: https://dictionary.findlaw.com/definition/publish.html#:~:text=1%20%3A%20to%20make%20known%20to,expression%20of%20one's%20last%20will

Comment: Oxford:  **Private** 1. belonging to or for the use of one particular person **or group** of people only.

Comment: Oxford:  **Publish** 1. prepare and issue (a book, journal, piece of music, etc.) for **public** sale, distribution, or readership.

Comment: Your definition is specific to "purposes of defamation" only. You are taking a specific corner case and trying to expand its limited applicability to everything.  ("can I *publish* a secret to you? It will be *public*, just between you and I" said no person ever.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151337/discussion-on-answer-by-nvoigt-do-you-need-consent-when-taking-a-screenshot-duri); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.